# Data Compression Video Tutorials?

Tags: compression

Does anyone know where I can find video/screencast tutorials on data compression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know of any videos or screencast, but my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386930/best-compression-algorithm-with-the-following-features/386946#386946) from a smiliar question may help...

Comment: Great Thanks!  It's hard to find videos on it.  I can find some on you tube, but that's about it. Everytime I google "Data Compression Videos", I get results about Video Compression, lol.